# ESLint HTML report using webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, eslint

How do I get ESLint HTML report using the WebPack config. I'm currently using `eslint-loader`. The [documentation](http://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/formatters/#html) on ESLint formatter is not clear.

In `webpack.config.js`, I have the following added as preloaders.

```
preLoaders: [{
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
        loaders: ['eslint-loader'],
    }],
```

It does the job perfectly and shows errors in the console when I run WebPack. I have additionally added in WebPack

```
eslint: {
        formatter: require("eslint/lib/formatters/html"),
    },
```

Which throws HTML output string in the console itself. I would like to get it/save as HTML file. Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

You may also need to specify the output file in your webpack.config.js as in:

```
...
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        loader: 'babel',
      },
      {
          test: /\.js$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['babel-loader', 'eslint-loader' ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "src"),
    filename: "client.min.js"
  },
  eslint: {
    configFile: './.eslintrc',
    outputReport: {
      filePath: 'eslint_checkstyle_[hash].xml',
      formatter: require('eslint/lib/formatters/checkstyle'),
    }
  },
...
```